# String coming with an extra new line

Tags: powershell, newline

Below is the code where I am taking server names from a text file and concatenating with comma.
But when I am printing the value, it is coming with an extra new line after the values.

I tried doing `$erversToReboot.Trim()`, but didn't helped.

```
$ServerList = Get-Content "D:\ServerName.txt"
$Servers=""
foreach($Server in $ServerList)
{

        $Servers += $Server + ","

}

[string]$ServersToReboot= $Servers.TrimEnd(",")
```

The output coming as

```
server1,server2
---one extra line here---
```

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

Comment: try using `$ServerList -join ','` instead of building it semi-manually. [*grin*]

Comment: [See this document to GREATLY simplify what you're doing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#split-and-join-operators)

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. My guess is that there's an empty line at the end of your input file. Like @tommymaynard already wrote in his answer: use -join. Do not write loops and stuff for things if there's an operator for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best as I can tell, you're attempting to comma separate your servers. I'd skip the Foreach construct myself and simply use the join operator.

```
$ServerList = Get-Content -Path 'D:\ServerName.txt'
$ServerList -join ','
```

This can be done in a single statement, as well.

```
$ServerList = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\ServerName.txt') -join ','
```

Tommy

Comment: Definitely the right solution in general (though we still don't know what happened in the OP's case).

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, it's in general much simpler to use the `-join` operator to join the input lines with a specifiable separator.

As for the problem of an extra empty line:  [Gert Jan Kraaijeveld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10794331/gert-jan-kraaijeveld) plausibly suggests that your input file has an extra empty line at the end, while noting that it is actually *not* what would happen with the code you've posted, which *should work fine* (despite its inefficiency).

Perhaps the extra line is an artifact of how you're *printing* the resulting value.

---

To answer the related question of **how to ignore empty lines in the input file**:

Assuming that it is OK to simply remove *all* empty lines from the input, the simplest PowerShell-idiomatic solution is:

```
@(Get-Content D:\ServerName.txt) -ne '' -join ','
```

`@(Get-Content D:\ServerName.txt)` returns the input lines as an array<sup>[1]</sup> of strings, from which 
`-ne ''` then removes empty lines, and the result of which `-join` joins with separator `,`

---

<sup>[1] `Get-Content D:\ServerName.txt` would return a *scalar* (single string), if the input file happened to contain only *1* line, because PowerShell generally reports a *single* output object *as itself* rather than as a *single-element array* when pipeline output is *collected*.

Because of that, `@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator - instead of just `(...)` - is needed in the above command: it ensures that the output from `Get-Command` is treated as an *array*, because the `-ne` operator acts differently with a *scalar* LHS and returns a *Boolean* rather than filtering the LHS's elements: compare `'foo' -ne ''` to `@('foo') -ne ''`.

By contrast, the `@(...)` is *not* necessary if you pass the result (directly) to `-join` (which simply is a *no-op* with a scalar LHS):

`(Get-Content D:\ServerName.txt) -join ','`</sup>